# Using sitelinks search bar google

Tags: seo, google-search, schema.org, google-rich-snippets, json-ld

I am following [this guide by Google](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/slsb-overview) to add a sitelinks search bar on my website. The structured data markup tool shows everything to be correct. But:

1. The search bar hasn't appeared in the search results for my website.
2. Google has indexed the page `www.example.com/search?q=%7Bsearch_term_string%7D` instead:

   [image: Screenshot of google search result]

I have the exact same code as explained in the example, except the site URL of course. What am I doing wrong? Or is this expected behaviour?

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "WebSite",
  "url": "http://www.example.com/",
  "potentialAction": {
    "@type": "SearchAction",
    "target": "http://www.example.com/search?q={search_term_string}",
    "query-input": "required name=search_term_string"
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: how long ago did you make the change? And i presume that http://www.example.com/search?q=news (for example)  would return all entries with the word 'news' from your website if typed into the browser's address bar?

Comment: It's been over a week now. Yes, it would return all entries, products in my case, containing the word 'news'. The page title would say `Search results for 'news'`, if that is important.

Comment: has your site's home page been recrawled and is the code above on the home page only?

Comment: I believe it is recrawled, since the URL `http://www.example.com/search?q=%7Bsearch_term_string%7D` is indexed on Google. 
The code is on every page. Should it only be on the homepage?

Comment: the instructions say only on the home page, but don't mention if it can be on other pages as well
**2. Put the schema.org markup on your homepage
Your home page is the only page that requires markup to specify a Sitelinks search box**

There is also `Search box not displaying? The Sitelinks search box appears only for navigational queries and when relevant for users. Google algorithms use a variety of factors to determine when the search box appears, including the information on the site and different types of navigational queries from Search users`

try adding a rare word when using search?

Comment: Well, I'll remove it from other pages and see what happens after some time. Maybe, there aren't enough search users for my website to qualify for the search bar. Thanks.

Comment: I looked again at my code which was added very recently for the reason reason and isn't working. Pasting the HTML into the structured data tester returns no errors - but entering the url gives an error for JSON-LD. Wondered if you had the same in case it's a google syntax error in the example.

Comment: No, I checked using the URL. It says it's all good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are searching incorrectly, search for either **example** or **example.com** instead:

[image]
According to [this](https://moz.com/blog/sitelinks-search-box) a large number of searches are needed before google will display it - moz.com states that:

**Does your site receive a high volume of navigational or branded search traffic?**
For example, keyword phrases such as 'moz' and 'moz.com' send this website thousands of visits per week. Branded and navigational search volume is a good, but not perfect, indicator of the likeliness of the sitelinks search box to appear.

Comment: No, searching for `example` or `example.com` doesn't show the bar, either. But yes, I don't think it does receive a high volume of search traffic.

Comment: This seems to work for low volume of search traffic (ie works on the site I'm working on). Recrawling and leaving it 2 days makes it show up. Further testing showed that including the code on multiple pages gave the sitelinks underneath, but not the free text search box at the bottom. If it's not working check the CSS and HTML in a validator and then inspect the DOM - something must be conflicting since the code is very short and clearly correct.