# Does sitelinks search box schema provided by Google work for blogger blogs?

Tags: seo, blogger, schema.org, google-rich-snippets

I am a blogger and I am trying to show a `sitelinks` search box for my blog in Google search results. My blog appears in search results properly - you can check by googling "101helper". A `sitelinks` search box does not show up in Google results, though. I am using this code provided by Google:

```
<script type="application/ld+json"> 
{ "@context": "http://schema.org", "@type": "WebSite", "url": "http://101helper.blogspot.com/", "potentialAction": { "@type": "SearchAction", "target": "http://101helper.blogspot.com/p/search.html?cx=015429047261654082873:l2wznrj5qrq&cof=FORID%3A10&ie=UTF-8&q={search_term_string}", "query-input": "required name=search_term_string" } }
</script>
```

How can I get the `sitelinks` search box to show up in the search results for my blog?

Comment: it now works, I get the site links for - About, How to Increase, Beginner to blogging, How To Add Logo, etc

Comment: I get sitelinks but sitelink search box isn't appearing can you tell me why is it so?

Comment: it might be about how you are searching for it - try just typing in your domain name including the .net or .com to be sure, and see what happens.  Check if the google structured data testing tool see the json-ld for sitelinks

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31662330/using-sitelinks-search-bar-google/31755793#31755793